# How can I allow a download to pause/resume?

Tags: php, http, download

Normally, when I want to allow a user to download a file without revealing the exact location, I just use something like this to let them download the file:

```
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $filename) . "\";");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($filename));
readfile("$filename");
```

But if they are using a modern browser or other download client, and they pause the download and try to resume it, the script (assuming they are still authenticated or whatever) will resend the headers and the file contents from the beginning, thus breaking the download, and basically requiring the file to be redownloaded from the beginning.

How can I enable my script to compensate for paused (and consequentially, resumed) downloads?

Comment: Do you really need this functionality? Do your protected downloads come from user uploads? If so, what is your limit on upload size? If its 50MB or less, I'd say its ok not to have this functionality. Or, if they're all files you generate and the average size is equally small, its probably not needed. On the other hand, if they're all very large files, you could consider doing something like distributing them as a torrent, then protecting the download of the torrent file. Its not as secure as users can then share torrent files - just something to think about.

Comment: As of this moment in time, I am asking how only to seek the knowledge, not to use it in any particular project. I have wanted this functionality in past projects, and I will probably in the future. I just thought I'd ask while I'm in no hurry to find the answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use php's built-in fopen to open the file and then fseek to the right place (based on the range in the request header) and then return the partial file using fpassthru instead of using readfile.

You can find some example code in php under the comments for [fread](http://ee.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php#84115)

Comment: I haven't yet tested that code, but it's exactly what I was looking for, so I'm accepting this as the answer.

Answer (score 5):

You need to read the request headers like Range, If-Range, etc then seek to the correct location in the file. Normally a web-server would do this for you on an ordinary file. It's a bit complex but here's something that might get you started:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1218116.aspx

http://www.notes411.com/dominosource/tips.nsf/0/480C4E3BE825F69D802571BC007D5AC9!opendocument

For the second link the code is in part 12

Comment: Those are both great links... but I don't understand the code in those examples. Any PHP-centric tutorials or similar you know of? Google is currently not being its usual helpful self...